# Can a for-compr yield 2 seperate variables

Tags: scala

I was wondering if it is possible for a for-compr to yield 2 vals like:

```
val user, account = 
  for {
      user <-  ...
      account <- ..
  } yield (user, account)
```

If this is possible, how can I explicitly set the type like:

```
val user: Future[User], account: Future[Account] = for {... }
```

When I try the above, the first variable has both results in it like this:

```
val result = 
   for { 
    ..
   } yield (user, account)


result._1
result._2
```

I personally don't like referring to data with _1 and _2 so I was hoping I could return 2 seperate vals in one-go.

Possible?

Comment: Not possible with futures, because the for-comprehension will return a `Future`, which can't be pattern matched without blocking. For other types, this is not a great idea either, because there will be a possibility of a match error when the for-comprehension fails early.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the type of `result` would be `Future[(User, Account)]`, so `result._1` and `result._2` don't make any sense. It would have to be something like this:

```
result map { r =>
  r._1  // user
  r._2  // account
}
```

You can improve things a bit by using a *pattern matching anonymous function*:

```
result map {
  case (user, account) => ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pattern matching when initializing vals.

```
val (x, y) = (5, 10.0)
x: Int = 5
y: Double = 10.0
```

so in your case

```
val (user: Future[User], account: Future[Account]) = for {... }
```

Comment: As danielnixon points out, this answer isn't actually correct.

Comment: This is very wrong. `val (a, b) = for(i <- Future.successful(1); j <- Future.successful(2)) yield (i, j)` will fail. @Blankman did you even try this?